# ExtJs Grid row hover color and high

Tags: css, extjs4, sass

I'm new to **Extjs** and I need to style my grid row but I can't figured out how to do two important things, give a `minHeight` to all the ROW and disable or give different color when mouse hover on the rows that are Alternate rows.

So one will be white with white hover `background-color` and the other will be gray with gray hover background-color.

All the solutions that I found on the web are pretty old and doesn't work at least for me.
Anyone with the same problem recently?

Answer (score 3):

"Basic" white rows have `x-grid-row` and "Grey" rows have both `x-grid-row` and `x-grid-row-alt` classes. When you move mouse over them them get `x-grid-row-over` class. So you could do something like this:

```
tr.x-grid-row.x-grid-row-over  td{
    background-color: yellow;
}
tr.x-grid-row-alt.x-grid-row-over td{
    background-color: red;
}
```

As for `minHeight`, if I understand it correctly, you need to set it in every column definition. So something like:

```
columns: [
{
   text: 'Column 1',
   minHeight: 100,
   ...
},
{
   text: 'Column 2',
   minHeight: 100,
   ...
},
...
]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I think I messed up a bit with background color, anyway thanks to you now work perfectly! About the minHeight I mean I need to apply to the ROW not to the Column.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in `sass` (sass/var/grid/Panel.scss) by setting the following [CSS vars](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-css_var-S-grid-row-cell-over-background-color):

```
$grid-row-cell-alt-background-color : color;
$grid-row-cell-over-background-color : color;
$grid-row-cell-background-color: color;
$grid-row-cell-focus-border-color : none;
```

You could also set the `minHeight` of your column like this:

```
columns : {
    items : mColumns,

    defaults : {
        minHeight : yourMinHeight
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for the replay, I already did what you suggest for the color but in that way the hover works just for all the rows not alternate (kind of stupid thing from ExtJs). About minHeight I need to style the minHeight of ROW not colum